# SAS proc ds2 YEAR function

Tags: multithreading, sas, sas-ds2

I get an odd error code while trying to get a DS2 thread up and running.

```sas
   proc ds2;
   thread work.th_ieb /overwrite=yes;
   dcl DOUBLE Beg_Jahr;
   METHOD RUN();
    set {select id, date
       from DATA
       };
    IF FIRST.id THEN DO;
    Beg_Jahr    = YEAR(DATE);
    OUTPUT;
    END;
 END;
endthread;
run;
```

The Error is:

```sas
ERROR: Compilation error.
ERROR: Illegal conversion for date or time type. Source line 34.
```

It works fine without the YEAR function. Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure that the type associated with the variable you've called `date` actually has a date type. In `PROC DS2`, there is actually a date data type, unlike in "traditional" SAS, where dates are stored as the number of days since January 1st, 1960.

Comment: Even If I add 'dcl DATE date' its not running.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full sample program I used to reproduce your issue and this version works at my site. One key change is the format of 'dt' using 11.0 instead of date9 in the sas source data. I could not make it work with date9 even though the SAS docs say it should.

```
data stuff;
  format dt 11.0 id 11.0;
    dt='01JAN2015'd;
    id = 1;
run;

proc ds2;
    thread work.th_ieb /overwrite=yes;
        dcl double Beg_Jahr;
        dcl date ds2_dt having format yymmdd10.;

        METHOD RUN();
          set {select id, dt
                 from stuff
                order by id
              };
          by id;

            ds2_dt = to_date(dt);
            put ds2_dt=;

            IF FIRST.id THEN DO;
                Beg_Jahr = year(dt);
                put beg_jahr=;
                OUTPUT;
            END;
        END;
    endthread;

    data;
        dcl thread th_ieb t_inst;

        method run();
          set from t_inst threads=2;
        end;
    enddata;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

I freely admit that I don't fully understand all of the intricacies of DS2, but this solution works for me.

Change the name of the variable you've called `date` to something else since `date` is a keyword in  DS2. DS2 is much pickier than base SAS about those things. Here I'll call the variable `birthdt` just for the sake of example.

Make sure that the date variable is numeric in the input dataset.

```
proc ds2;
    thread work.th_ieb / overwrite = yes;
        dcl double beg_jahr;
        method run();
            set {
                select id, birthdt
                from data
            };
            if first.id then do;
                beg_jahr = year(birthdt);
                output;
            end;
        end;
    endthread;
run;
quit;
```